# Constraint to generate random integers

Tags: algorithm, random, constraints

I have some array of integers that I generate randomly for example between 0 and 9.
I have a set of constraints that I need to apply to this generation.

For example :
1) Constraint 1 -> the numbers at even position in the array should be 0 or 1.
2) Constraint 2 -> the array should have at least one 0 and at least one 1 on even values 
etc ...

What I do for now :
I generate randomly the numbers array.
Then for each even position, I randomly pick between 0 and 1.
Then I check that for each even value, I have at least one 0 and at least one 1. If not, I regerate all the values with the constraint above (Then for each even position, I randomly pick between 0 and 1.) until I have something which works (in a do for).
However, this works good because these are very simple constraints.

3) Constraint 3 -> the sum of the differences between the numbers should be superior to a certain value.

etc ...
The issue I have is that it is inter dependent constraints problems and I dont want to encapsulate do while in another do while, etc ... when I add one constraint.

What would be the proper way to achieve this in the cleanest way possible?

Edit:

I realized I was not clear at all... My apologies.
I edited the constraints to make it easier to understand.

My code looks like that (typed on notepad++ might be mistakes) :

```
        std::vector<int> myVector;
        int N = 100; // vector contains 100 values
        do{
            myVector.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                if(i%2==0){
                    myVector.push_back(rand() % 2);
                }
                else{
                    myVector.push_back(rand() % 10);
                }
            }
        }while(!doesContains0and1(myVector));

     bool MyClass::doesContains0and1(std::vector<int> avector)
    {
        bool returnVal = true;
        for(int i=0;i<avector.size;i++){
          if(i%2==0){
            if(!avector.contains(0) || !avector.contains(1){
                returnVal = false;
            }
          }
        }
     return returnVal;
}
```

The 3) constraint means, if I have for example :

0 5 1 7 0 9 0 1 1

that there is a constraint on abs(5-0) + abs (1-5) + abs(7-1) + ... etc > a certain value

These constraints are examples, I am more looking for some methodology than pure code :)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Show us what you've done, to begin with.

Comment: This is not particularly clear.

Comment: Could you post an example of the array output that you would like?

Comment: If you're likely to have a number of constraints, you might want to read up on [constraint programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming).

Comment: The two constraints contradict each other, both cannot be true at the same time

Comment: I think that he's trying to construct an array that has the even indices be a random boolean. Then in each group of 10 indices ( 0-9, 10-19, etc) the values at the even indices must have at least one 1 and one 0. so indices 0,2,4,6, and 8 cannot all be 0 or 1; one of them has to be a 1 and one has to be a 0. Like I said, Im not sure how to interpret the 3rd constraint but this explains the first 2

Comment: Chase you were completely right in your understanding. I simplified the constraints to make it easier. forget about the subsets ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me take a stab at this...

```
int sum;
for (int i = 0 ; i < array_size ; i++){

    if (!(i % 10)) sum = 0; // resets the sum to 0

    if(i % 2){ //even or odd
        //odd
        sum += array[i] = rand() % 2; // 1 or 0
        if ((!(i % 10)) && (sum == 0 || sum == 5)) 
            array[i] = sum?0:1;

    }else{
        //even
        array[i] = rand();

    }
}
```

This follows the first 2 constraints. The sum will count the number of 1's in each subset of 10. All 0's will yield a sum of 0 and all 1's will yield a sum of 5. It will set the last element accordingly.

I'm not sure how to interpret the 3rd constraint, but hopefully this gets you started

Comment: Chase, This works thank you. However, as I just explained in my update, I am more looking for a general methodology for these kinds of constraints.

Comment: The methodology for any kind of algorithm depends entirely on the constraints. I'm still not 100% sure what you are asking for; A methodology for this algorithm specifically or for writing algorithms in general? There isn't one way to constrain values but the only way to do so is with methods like the one I posted. It depends entirely on the how you want to constrain it.

Comment: Thank you Chase. I am looking for a general method for this specific case, which means, an array of integers with very little size(in my example it's 100) but it will be more around 10. Then I have constraints like the one I posted. It is very important that it remains random, which means, I don't want to have an array which will work, I want to have this array randomly as well. I was thinking about brute force method by trying randomly, and when one constraint is broken, I regenerate all the numbers, and so on ... Then if you say that it depends on the constraints themselves, it's another pb

Comment: You could (if we include the subsets from before) have it check the subset against the constraints and if it fails, regenerate just that subset until it does.

Comment: Yes indeed! And for the 3rd constraint do you have any idea how to mix it with the other ones?

Comment: You could have a running total, similar to my code but have it be `if (i % 10 && i != 0) { sum += abs(array[i] - array[i - 1]); } else { if (sum < threshold) i -= 10; sum = 0;}` the if statement makes sure that the difference isn't called on i=0 because the index -1 does not exist and it will throw an error. If the sum is less than a certain value, it will subtract 10 from the index counter and essentially start the generation over again for that subset. Is this what you want?

Comment: it generates over and over again if it is in a do while doesn't it?

Comment: Put it in a for loop. It will not loop infinitely.

Comment: Hum. I don't understand that :) How can you put it in a for loop if you don't know how many times you will need to regenerate the subset?

Comment: The `i -= 10` will decrement the counter so that it will regenerate the subset again. For example if it reaches 20 and it doesn't work, it will go back to 10. Then on the next loop, i is still less than the 100 and i is incremented by 1. It will regenerate 11-20 once more and on 20, check the constraints